# How to tell if USB 3.0 UASP mode is enabled?

Tags: usb-storage, usb-3

In Windows 7 (64-bit Pro) is there a way to tell if a connected USB 3.0 drive is running with UASP enabled?

Comment: Here is an article on it.  There are some requirements.  Verify your hardware meets those requirements.  http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3-uas-turbo,3215-4.html

Answer (score 3):

in CrystalDiskInfo in the field "Interface" you can see if UASP is used.

Example an USB 3.0 device which use UASP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test procedure for your connected USB 3.0 drive:

1. Open up Ai Suite II, and click on the [USB 3.0 Boost] from under [Tool]:
2. Select the desired device, followed by the mode selection button to switch between different modes:
3. Logo will change to indicate the status of the USB 3.0 device:

Comment: That's OEM specific, won't work for the vast majority of builds.